# Why am I getting 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present' here?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

My stored procedure is the simple one-liner

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckIfFinished    
    @pid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
AS  
BEGIN
    SELECT finished 
    FROM Partners 
    WHERE id = @pid   
END
```

and I'm calling it from my C# code like

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CheckIfFinished", this._Conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", pid);

    this._Conn.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        finished = dataReader.GetByte(0) == 1 ? true : false;
    }

    this._Conn.Close();
}
```

The column `finished` in the `Partners` table is of type `TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`

Stack trace of error is

> [InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is
>   present.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckDataIsReady(Int32
>   columnIndex, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn, Boolean permitAsync,
>   String methodName) +6531242
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean
>   setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn) +81
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean
>   setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn) +25
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetByte(Int32 i) +27
>   Survey.Models.SurveyDbModel.CheckIfFinished(Guid pid) +230

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot `dataReader.Read()`.

Until you don't execute `Read()` on a data reader, the data is not available.